# Price extraction in java

Tags: java, jsoup, discord

I am trying to create a discord bot that searches up an item inputted by user `"!price item"` and then gives me a price that I can work with later on in the code. I figured out how to get the `html` code into a string or a doc file, but I am struggling on finding a way to extract only prices.

Here is the **code**:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event) {
    String html;
    System.out.println("I received a message from " +
            event.getAuthor().getName() + ": " +
            event.getMessage().getContentDisplay());
    if (event.getMessage().getContentRaw().contains("!price")) {
        String input = event.getMessage().getContentDisplay();
        String item = input.substring(9).replaceAll(" ", "%20");
        String URL = "https://www.google.lt/search?q=" + item + "%20price";
        try {
            html = Jsoup.connect(URL).userAgent("Mozilla/49.0").get().html();
            html = html.replaceAll("[^\\ ,.£€eur0123456789]"," ");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return;
        }
        System.out.println(html);
    }
}
```

The biggest problem is that I am using google search so the prices are not in the same place in the `html` code. Is there a way I can extract only `(numbers + EUR) or (a euro sign + price)` from the html code?.

Comment: Google will return the price from many sources. What exactly you're looking for ?

Comment: @Makky The thing is what the bot is going to look for depends on the user that made the input, so it could be anything from a teapot to a car, that why I am struggling if it was only one item I could simply go on some general website that sells cars or any item that I want to look up and then take the information from there.

Comment: I normally see if similiar library is available. In this case you can use this one https://github.com/afedulov/google-web-search

Comment: @Makky If you have time could you please explain how I could implement this library?

Comment: Juse extract the source code from it or use it as MAVEN dependecny

Answer (score 0):

you can easily do that scrapping the website. Here's a simple working example to do what you are looking for using **JSOUP**:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String query = "oneplus";
            String url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + query + "%20price&client=firefox-b&source=lnms&tbm=shop&sa=X";
            int pricesToRetrieve = 3;
            ArrayList<String> prices = new ArrayList<String>();

            Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0").get();
            Elements elements = document.select("div.pslires");

            for (Element element : elements) {
                String price = element.select("div > div > b").text();
                String[] finalPrice = price.split(" ");
                prices.add(finalPrice[0] + finalPrice[1]);
                pricesToRetrieve -= 1;

                if (pricesToRetrieve == 0) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            System.out.println(prices);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

That piece of code will output:

> [347,10€, 529,90€, 449,99€]

And if you want to retrieve more information just connect JSOUP to the **Google Shop** url adding your desired query, and scrapping it using JSOUP. In this case I scrapped Google Shop for OnePlus to check its prices, but you can also get the url to buy it, the full product name, etc. In this piece of code I want to retrieve the first 3 prices indexed in Google Shop and add them to an ArrayList of String. Then before adding it to the ArrayList I split the retrieved text by "space" so I just get the information I want, the price.

This is a simple scrapping example, if you need anything else feel free to ask! And if you want to learn more about scrapping using JSOUP [check this link](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax).

Hope this helped you!